# I didn't find Windows 10’s Timeline feature?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Where i can find Windows 10’s Timeline feature? I updated windows but still i cannot see. I have **windows 10 Pro version 1703**. I want to timeline my visual studio history. I didn't find the icon in the bottom as shown.

Comment: It is part of the April 2018 update. You need to update to 1803.

Answer (score 3):

The feature was released in the April 2018 update, **version 1803**. You are a whole year behind.

In versions which have it, the Timeline is accessible via <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> and replaces/extends the workspace (virtual desktop) switcher.